# Vue 3: Why can I not set two ref's with the same object

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

**The problem:**

Whenever I try to set two ref variables with the same Object they will share the same reactivity inside of the component.

When I click the checkbox ref1.test and ref2.test will change both, while the v-model is only for ref1.test

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  ref1: {{ ref1 }} ref2: {{ ref2 }}

  <input type="checkbox" v-model="ref1.test" />
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, ref } from "vue";
import { TestModel } from "@/TestModel";

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {

    const testObj = { test: false } as TestModel;

    const ref1 = ref<TestModel>({});
    ref1.value = testObj;

    const ref2 = ref<TestModel>({});
    ref2.value = testObj;

    return {
      ref1,
      ref2,
    };
  },
});
</script>
```

**TestModel.ts**

```
export interface TestModel {
  test?: boolean;
}
```

Can someone explain this or tell me if this is normal? (I know how to solve this, but I just wanna know why this is happening)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because Vue's reactivity is just proxy. It uses proxy so it knows what to do when a value change.

Proxy A (ref1) -> read/write testObj

Proxy B (ref2) -> read/write testObj

Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy

According to the Vue's docs

`ref` does the following:

> If an object is assigned as a ref's value, the object is made deeply reactive with reactive().

Docs: https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#ref

`reactive` does the following:

> Returns a reactive proxy of the object.
>
> ...
>
> The returned object and its nested objects are wrapped with ES Proxy

Docs: https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#reactive

Answer (score 1):

The two ref's properties (`ref1`,`ref2`) refers to the same object which `testObj` and any change in one of those properties affects the original one, this is a javascript behavior, to avoid it try to clone the object deeply using [`structuredClone`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone) :

```js
    const testObj = { test: false } as TestModel;

    const ref1 = ref<TestModel>({});
    ref1.value = structuredClone(testObj);

    const ref2 = ref<TestModel>({});
    ref2.value = structuredClone(testObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem, with the difference of just using plain JS and not TS. The example from @Boussadjra_Brahim is slightly wrong here.
`structuredClone()` can't be called on proxy objects. So you have to call `toRaw()` on the proxy first.

```
import { ref,toRaw} from 'vue'

const testObj = ref({})
testObj.value = await callMyObj();

const ref1 = ref({});
ref1.value = structuredClone(toRaw(testObj.value));

const ref2 = ref({});
ref2.value = structuredClone(toRaw(testObj.value));
```